Failing to map PointCloud2 topic to octomap_server cloud_in
I have an Ouster sensor which I am attempting to use to incrementally build an OctoMap of an indoor environment.
PointCloud2 data is successfully published on the /ouster/points topic and can be visualised in RViz.
When running octomap server with the following launch file no data is output from octomap (through topics such as through /free_cells_vis_array).
<launch>
    <node pkg="octomap_server" exec="octomap_server_node" name="octomap_server">
        <param name="resolution" value="0.05" />

        <!-- fixed map frame (set to 'map' if SLAM or localization running!) -->
        <param name="frame_id" value="os_sensor" />
        
        <param name="latch" value="false" />

        <!-- maximum range to integrate (speedup!) -->
        <param name="sensor_model/max_range" value="5.0" />
        
        <!-- data source to integrate (PointCloud2) -->
        <remap from="cloud_in" to="/ouster/points" />
    </node>
</launch>

Looking at the rqt_graph, cloud_in seems to have been mapped to /narrow_stereo/points_filtered2.

I am new to ROS and a bit stuck. Answers to similar questions talk about the frame/tf needing to be correct. I am not sure if this is correct/relevant in my case. I have not had any success with various frame_id values (such as "map").
Thanks
